# NSDataDetector with NSTextCheckingTypeLink doesn't detect some particular links

Tags: ios

I have a method that's supposed to detect links from string, using `NSDataDetector` :

```
extension String
{
    func isLink() -> Bool {

        var urlString = self
        let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matchesInString(self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count))

        if matches.count > 0 {
             return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

It works pretty well, but for some particular strings, it doesn't ( for instance : **lll.pm** ).
I don't really know what to do, this link works on Safari and on Chrome, so I guess they are using something different to detect links.